# How to perform a for loop array in perl scripting

Tags: perl, shell

In Shell scripting i usually loop through the array in this way

```
something[0]="abc"
something[1]="bcd"
something[2]="def"

for i in "${something[@]}"
do
   do something
done
```

I want to perform this same kind of operation in perl. Please suggest.

Comment: This is one of the first questions i have ever seen where asking and reading the answers takes more effort then if you just had researched yourself. You would have had to enter way less characters into google to get the same results instantly.

Answer (score 1):

That is the syntax:

```
foreach my $value (@something)
{
  do something

}
do
```

Comment: Hi what's $value here? It's similar to "i"?

Comment: @ramaswamy Yes that is the same. It is the entry from the array.

Comment: Technically, `$value` here is an _alias_ to the element in the `@something` array. So you can print it, but you can also change it.

Comment: @Sobrique makes an important point. That one will bite you if you're not careful!

Answer (score 0):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @something = ('abc','bcd','def');

foreach (@something){
    print "$_\n"; #$_ is default varaible for print the each element of array
}
```

Array print by the index key value. like `$something[0]` give `abc`
so in the forloop

```
for my $i(0..$#something){ 
print "$something[$i]\n"; 
}
```

Here `$#something` is the last element of array. `..` is the range operator

And also do this

```
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#something; $i++){
    print "$something[$i]\n";
}
```

Comment: Personally, I can think of very few good reasons to use a `for` loop for array iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
my @allNames = ('Lee', 'Coo', 'Bee');
foreach my $name (@allNames)
{
    print "$name\n";
}
```

Each element in `@allNames` is assigned to `$name` in turn, and the code in the curly braces is executed.

Comment: I'd suggest a minor amendment - it's not assigned to, as much as `$name` being an _alias_. So you can do `$name =~ s/[ae]/x/g;` and it'll modify the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/perl
$something[0]="abc";
$something[1]="bcd";
$something[2]="def";

for $i (@something) {
   print "do something with $i\n";
}
```

This is as close to Perl as what you have in your BASH script. In Perl `@something` is an array variable. `$something[0]` is the first item in `@something`.

This is a pretty basic Perl question. I suggest you get a copy of the [Llama Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) and learn yourself some Perl.